# Validate email and ban certain domains

Tags: php, email, validation

I have this code I currently use to validate emails:

```
return (bool) preg_match('/^([a-z0-9\+\_\-\.]+)@([a-z0-9\+\_\-\.]{2,})(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/i', $arg0);
```

How can I modify that code so I can ban several domains? I don't want any extra files to add, just to modify this code.

Thank you.

Comment: You already banned anything from the `.museum` TLD

Comment: What have you tried?  What specific problems are you having?  This comes across as a "CODE THIS FOR ME!" post.

Comment: As answer to the actual regex question: you can use an `(?!xxx|yyy)` assertion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be to have an array with banned providers:

`$providers = Array ( 'gmail.com', 'yahoo.com' );`

and then just loop trough that array and check if provided email contains `'@' . $provider`.